# split monolithic frontend in independent project and compose them in a single page

Tags: vue.js, frontend, microservices

We have a monolithic spa composed by 3 distinct "apps". Layout is divided in two parts

- header: navbar containing links to apps +  user information
- main container: where selected app is rendered.

Everything was developed in a single repository even if every app is completely indipendent from other.
Now, we are rewriting frontend in vuejs + vuetify and need to split this monolith into indipendent projects we don't know what is the best solution to share the navbar between every app.

This are some solutions we googled:

- use iframes -> usually iframes are not recomended
- use ssi -> there are lack of resource and seems too complicated to set up and manage
- deploy single apps as "web components"(vue-cli build -wc) -> web components created by vue-cli rely on a global VUE object and not sure this can work properly + performance could suffer

Are there some KISS patterns for our problem?

Projects like mosaic9, single-spa or similar are too much for our use case.

Thank you.

Comment: Is the navbar a vue component? If not, it should be. Why not just import it into all apps that need it? Put it in a common folder that all apps can import from.

Comment: We are splitting our codebase and want to avoid inter-project dependency. If we made a change on navbar we have to redeploy all other apps. Navbar is a vue component.